# Edit variables inherited from parent class

Tags: c++, oop, variables, encapsulation

I have this code for a basic entity system I'm testing

**Enity.h**

```
class Enemy
{
    public:
    void attack(Player player);
    virtual void die();

    protected:  //Info variables
    int attackDamage;
    std::string name;
    bool alive;
}

class ChildEnemy1 : public Enemy
{
    name = "Enemy1" //Invalid
};

class ChildEnemy2 : public Enemy
{
    name = "Enemy2" // Invalid
};
```

How would you change the Info variables (attackDamage, name, alive) without inheriting a public setter function 
(retain encapsulation).

EDIT: This is not a duplicate question as I have not found an adequate answer to this problem on SO

Comment: Variable assignments can only be in functions, not at the top level of a class. If you want to initialize member variables, do it in the class constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the members in the constructor.

```
class ChildEnemy1 : public Enemy
{
    ChildEnemy1() : name("Enemy1") {}
};
```